# Web2Py tables broken migration

Tags: database, migration, web2py

I tried adding a new table into one of my models in Web2Py. In addition I added a new field to an existing table. I tried loading a page that used those tables and it didn't work, claimed those things don't exist. Okay so I get migrations to False here.

```
db = DAL('sqlite://storage.sqlite',pool_size=1,check_reserved=['all'], migrate = False)
```

Reloaded the page, no change. Then I tried doing something like this in the tables it wouldn't understand

```
db.define_table(....,migrate=False,fake_migrate=True)
```

and I changed the DAL call to be

```
db = DAL(...,fake_migrate_all=True)
```

As the web2py manual said. Still no change. So then I said well okay I will have to dumb the whole database. So I took everything out of my database folder and I tried to reload it with a clean slate.

Now it just doesn't load at all.

According to database administration none of the tables exist although if I check again in the database folder they are all there. If I try to load the application it immediately reports that none of my called tables exist. I have all the code backed up on a repo but I can't uninstall the current app because I don't have that kind of read access on the server this is running on.

Is there anything I can do?

Edit: By the way this is happening on SQLite

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried, besides dumbs DB, clean up the database folder? If you do not do this, web2py will goes insane, cuz the files says that there are tables, but db don't. Besides, take a look in [here](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Fixing-broken-migrations), about fixing broken migrations and some caveats about sqllite.